# vba: run time error '9'

Tags: vba, excel

When I want to copy the values of cells from one sheet to anoter in 6 Workbooks which are opened (in my case from "Sheet1" cells (B9:E111) to "Sheet2") I'm standing in front of the error: 'run time error 9 : Subscript out of range'
this is the code I wrote:

```
Sub sbCopyRangeToAnotherSheet()

  For i = 1 To 6

     Workbooks(i).Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").Value = Workbooks(i).Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B9:E111").Value  

  Next i

End Sub
```

May someone can help me? 
Thank you

Comment: You are trying to copy multiple cells into one.  Maybe try removing .value from both ends?  Or make the Range on the left half of the statement the same size as the right?

Comment: Do you have 6 workbooks open?  Do they all have a "Sheet2" and a "Sheet1"?  Also you are trying to put the value of many cells into one.

Comment: Rdster- I tried to put the same range (A1:D103) but same error.

Comment: Scott Carner - yes, all of them are opened, and have "sheet2" and "sheet1". I tried to put in the same range but still is not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all of your workbooks are open (the code below can work also if only 1, 2, or 3 are open), it will copy the values from `Range("B9:E111")` in `"Sheet2"` and paste them to "Sheet1" from Cell "A1".

```
Sub sbCopyRangeToAnotherSheet()

Dim i As Integer
Dim wb() As Workbook

' work with dynamic number of current open workbooks
ReDim wb(1 To Application.Workbooks.count)

For i = 1 To Application.Workbooks.count
    Set wb(i) = Workbooks(i)
    wb(i).Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B9:E111").Copy
    wb(i).Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlValues
Next i

End Sub
```

**Edit1**:

```
Sub sbCopyRangeToAnotherSheet()

Dim i As Integer
Dim wb() As Workbook

' work with dynamic number of current open workbooks
ReDim wb(1 To Application.Workbooks.Count)

For i = 1 To Application.Workbooks.Count
    Set wb(i) = Workbooks(i)
    wb(i).Worksheets(1).Range("B9:E111").Copy
    wb(i).Worksheets(2).Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlValues
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Unfortunately all the solutions that were suggested fail into the same error, while debugging the line in yelow is: "wb(i).Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B9:E111").Copy" in all the solutins (the line with the range ("B9:E111")

Comment: @Maya.R  are you sure you have a sheet named "sheet1" in all of your workbooks ? This is the name of the workbook , not the index

Comment: No, I changed the names of the sheets, "sheet1" and "sheet2" are their indexes. It worked when I didn't use the for loop and wrote the code for every workbook separately without index i, but I had to use the range ("A11:D103") and not only ("A1"). I don't know why it is not working with the loop.

Comment: @Maya.R try the code under **Edit1** and see if it works for you

Answer (score 5):

"Subscript out of range" means you're accessing an array/collection beyond its boundaries.

> ```
> Workbooks(i).Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").Value = Workbooks(i).Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B9:E111").Value
> ```

I count several different places in that single instruction that could throw that error. Split it up.

```
Dim book As Workbook
' if it blows up here, check how many books you have open:
Set book = Workbooks(i) 'consider looping from 1 To Workbooks.Count instead of 1 To 6

Dim source As Worksheet
' if it blows up here, check the filename of the book and whether it has a "Sheet1":
Set source = book.Worksheets("Sheet1") 

Dim destination As Worksheet
' if it blows up here, check the filename of the book and whether it has a "Sheet2":
Set destination = book.Worksheets("Sheet2")

' when it blows up here, consider exactly what you're trying to do:
destination.Range("A1").Value = source.Range("B9:E111").Value
```

The last instruction looks suspicious to me. If you're trying to paste `Sheet1!B9:E111` into `Sheet2!A1`, consider using `Copy`+`PasteSpecial` as in [Shai Rado's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40998597/1188513).

If you mean to iterate all open workbooks, consider a `For Each` loop instead:

```
Dim book As Workbook
For Each book In Workbooks
    '...
Next
```

Comment: Thanks for actually providing a well-thought complete answer that actually explains and addresses the real problem.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman thanks! I try to provide fishing rods instead of fish =)

Answer (score 1):

Try this, I think it is a problem to put the value of the whole range into one cell. I assign it first to an Array and then put the array on from what is A1 + the upper boundaries of the array...

```
Sub sbCopyRangeToAnotherSheet()

Dim vArr() As Variant

  For i = 1 To 6

     vArr = Workbooks(i).Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B9:E111").Value
     With Workbooks(i).Worksheets("Sheet2")
        .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(UBound(vArr, 1), UBound(vArr, 2))).Value = vArr
     End With
  Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: that means that you are referring to something that is not found, e.g. a workbook (we are iterating through 6 workbooks and presuming that we always have the same setup of data, which is, as others posted, a bit risky) In case you have another workbook open with a different setup, an error triggers. in case you don't have 6 but less workbooks open, an errror triggers.

Comment: if you could provide the whole code maybe even with the workbooks (e.g. dropbox), I'm certain we can fix it.

Comment: The answer of @ShaiRado solved the problem, you can take a look if you want. thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I'll warn that using workbook indexes like this is risky, but try this..

```
Sub sbCopyRangeToAnotherSheet()

   For i = 1 To 6
       Workbooks(i).Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B9:E111").Copy Workbooks(i).Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")
   Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Is it possible that you have another workbook open (like the one the macro is running in) that doesn't have a Sheet1 and Sheet2?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to do something like this:

```
Sub sbCopyRangeToAnotherSheet()

  For i = 1 To 6

     Workbooks(i).Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").Value = worksheetfunction.sum(Workbooks(i).Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B9:E111"))

  Next i

End Sub
```